# JQuery SimpleModal - Newbie here trying to get a simple asp form to open up in a modal window

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I found it very easy to implement modal windows that included an html or asp page in it with facebox but I wanted to give SimpleModal a try.

I was trying to learn how to use the Contact Form
http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/
but realized it was only for php.
I am a novice coder so please have some mercy. :) .

Anyhow what I was hoping to accomplish was to open up an asp page with a form in it.
I tried to do this with facebox but the form was not submitting to the form page but rather to the parent window.

Is there a simple way way to do this?
SimpleModal looks great but I found it so much harder to implement than facebox or thickbox.
At least with facebox or thickbox I could load html or asp pages in the window. I do not see an easy option for SimpleModal on how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry that you found SimpleModal difficult to use...my intention
was for it to be simple ;)

If you want to use SimpleModal with asp, you should try using the
appendTo option.

```
$(element).modal({appendTo:'form'});
```

To load external content into the dialog, you can do something like:

```
$.get("yourpage.html", function(data) {
    $(data).modal({appendTo:'form'});
});
```

I hope that helps.

-Eric

Comment: Hello Eric, 

You have got the be the most affable coder to date. Thank you.

I apologize I am not much of a coder so I am not really sure where to put that code.

I do know how to add the script tags at the header to point to the jquery scripts as well as the css files.

And with Facebox and Thickbox, I just add a rel="something" to the href.

Please forgive my newbness but where do I place the above code?
I know your simplemodal script must be special since I see it used in the Joomla app. Would love to find out for myself.

Sincere thanks.

Comment: Tucker - thanks for the compliment ;) SimpleModal is more of a modal dialog framework, so it relies more on the developer to tell it what to do. You should be able to create a js file and include it in your page - the js file will include the necessary js. Have a look at the demos on my site to get some ideas of what to put in the file. If you need further assistance, don't hesitate to email me.

-Eric